# ASP.NET Core 5 Web API Uploading Files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor

I am trying to work through uploading files with .Net 5 Web API and Blazor and struggling immensely with getting this implemented.

From everything I've gathered online, I have to have an upload control, where I read the uploaded file via the `OnInputChanged` event like so:

```
<InputFile OnChange="OnInputFileChanged" />

private void OnInputFileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.File != null)
        {    
            //EditEntity.Image is a FormFile
            this.EditEntity.Image = new FormFile(e.File.OpenReadStream(long.MaxValue), 0, e.File.Size, e.File.Name, e.File.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            this.EditEntity.Image = null;
        }
    }
```

One thing to add - FormFile doesn't seem to exist anywhere within `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` for me (`IFormFile` does, but not the implementation itself) and when I tried to add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 5.0.0` via NuGet, it throws this back: `Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 5.0.0' has a package type 'DotnetPlatform' that is not supported by project`. Thankfully, I was able to roll my own implementation and move on.

Documentation seems to be exceptionally sparse for uploading to a backend API, so inside my HttpClient instance I have a `PostAsFormAsync` model that creates a new `MultipartFormDataContent` instance, adding the JSON for my main payload, then I use reflection to retrieve the file(s) associated with that model - it's ugly, but this much seems to work and here's an example:

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

//add the default JSON serialization content
content.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), System.Text.Encoding.Default, "application/json"));

//now add anything that is an IFormFile via reflection
var props = model.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IFormFile)));
if (props.Count() > 0)
{
  foreach (var prop in props)
  {
    var file = (IFormFile)prop.GetValue(model);
    content.Add(new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream()), prop.Name, file.FileName);
  }
}

content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

//send it and ensure we get a proper response back
var responseMessage = await base.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

This all sends to the backend API, which has the following signature, but when the request arrives, the model instance is instantiated (meaning it's not null), but all properties are empty/default .Net values:

```
public override IActionResult UpdateEntity([FromForm] CategoryModel model)
{
  //model is instantiated here, but no values are mapped
}
```

I can see under the Network tab in my browser that Form Data is being sent with all of the values, but nothing is actually mapped.

If anyone has any suggestions - especially if it involves getting rid of reflection, because that feels wrong on so many levels - I'm open to anything!

Comment: Hi @Scott,So what is your real issue?Your metioned `OnInputFileChanged` seems not to be related to the httpclient below.What is your scenario?

Comment: Basically, whenever the model comes in to the backend API, no files are mapped anywhere and I the actual model instance is instantiated (so it's not null), but nothing is actually mapped to it - none of the properties have the expected values.